# auto mount problem

Tags: mount, backup, fstab, automount, cifs

I use this command for auto mounting in /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.1.205/Public /home/backup/ cifs auto,rw,user,username=admin,password=apassword,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

to mount a shared folder from my NAS server to my ubuntu 18.04 server but this command not executed when I reboot or shutdown my Ubuntu server

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo mount -a`?  This would give a hint on where the problem origniates.

Answer (score 0):

First we can establish it the mount point is valid 
`ls /home/backup` 
if directory is not avaliable then create a new directory 
`mkdir -p /mkdir /home/backup`

Then we can try to test your `/etc/fstab` by mounting all mount points 
`sudo mount -a`

Check logging of the syslog in `/var/log/syslog` for mount errors, using `grep` to filter `cifs` messages
`tail -100f /var/log/syslog |grep CIFS`

Please report back errors from syslog for further diagnose.